# Rails - relationship between models, how to set up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I am not sure on how to set up the relationships between models that are chain-like. The second depends on the first, the third depends on the first two and so on.

For example I have this:

```
Hardware HABTM OSes
OSes HABTM Apps
```

The problem comes when some Apps only work on certain Hardware. 
Should I set up an extra table and add there the apps that only work on certain hardware?
What would be the best way of setting this up?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: If I understood your problem correctly, then perhaps something like this could work for you:

```
class Hardware
  has_many :operating_systems
  has_many :applications, :through => operating_systems
end

class OperatingSystem
  has_many :applications
end

class Application
end
```

Comment: Thanks! So when I want to get all the apps based on hardware and os I will just intersect the two arrays I get, no?